# GET Request for /server-status every second

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging

I'm using an Linux server running Apache and Plesk and in the access_log, I'm seeing the following every 1 second;

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2014:14:20:06 +0000] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 15843 "-" "ELinks/0.12pre5 (textmode; Linux; -)"
```

I was wondering if this is normal?

Comment: I think you have mod_status enabled and this is due to that reason you are getting this in your log. you can disable it in httpd.conf file by commenting the line **#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so**

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Having [mod-status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html) enabled allows you or your tooling one way of checking the performance of your webserver.

Possibly the calls are made from your monitoring solution?

If you don't have monitoring or accounting enabled that number of requests would not be normal, although since they originate from localhost they're most likely not malicious either.

Comment: Thank you, i'll check mod_status. I was just concerned that it was checking so regularly that it might be having an impact on performance.

Comment: It's some monitoring probe, but a nervous one. The most paranoid ones will sample every 10 second (like Collectd), not more. Munin would do it every 5min as a default if I remember. Serving this status page every second is a piece of cake for Apache, you don't have to worry about performance. There's just something quite-not-right-but-not-wrong.